# QML - Selecting cells doesn't work and produces an error

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, qtquick2, qt6

I'm using `TableView` in QML with `QAbstractTableModel` in PyQt6, I'm trying to make the table cells (or rows) selectable and get its data using the code in this [documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#selecting-items), the table works fine and the data shows as intended but nothing is selectable.

**MyTableView.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Controls 


TableView {
    id: tableView
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    clip: true
    model: customTableModel
    onWidthChanged: tableView.forceLayout()
    selectionModel: ItemSelectionModel {
        onCurrentChanged: {
            console.log(currentIndex)  // This works
        }
    }

    selectionBehavior: TableView.SelectRows

    columnWidthProvider: function (column) { 
        return tableView.model ? tableView.width/tableView.model.columnCount() : 0
    }

    delegate: Rectangle {
        required property bool selected
        required property bool current

        implicitWidth: tableView.columnWidthProvider(column)
        implicitHeight: 40
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 1
        color: header ? "grey" : current ? "lightblue" : "white"
        clip: true

        Text {
            text: display
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.family: Style.font
            font.pointSize: Style.normalFont
            font.bold: header ? true : false
            color: header ? "white" : "black"
        }
    }
}
```

**table_model.py**

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, header, data, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.header = header
        self.datatable = data
        self.datatable.insert(0, {h: h.replace("_", " ").capitalize() for h in header.values()})

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent == QModelIndex():
            return len(self.datatable) if self.datatable else 0
        return 0

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent == QModelIndex():
            return len(self.header)
        return 0

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        # Heading
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole + 1:
            return index.row() == 0

        # Table Data
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()
            data = self.datatable[row][self.header[col]]
            return str(data) if data else ""

        return None
 
    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {
                 Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole: b"display",
                 Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole + 1: b"header"
                }
        return roles

    def flags(self, index):
        print("flags sent")
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

it gives these errors when I click on any table cell:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::layoutAboutToBeChanged(QList<QPersistentModelIndex>,QAbstractItemModel::LayoutChangeHint)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::layoutChanged(QList<QPersistentModelIndex>,QAbstractItemModel::LayoutChangeHint)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::modelReset()
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsAboutToBeMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsAboutToBeMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::rowsMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::columnsMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::layoutAboutToBeChanged(QList<QPersistentModelIndex>,QAbstractItemModel::LayoutChangeHint)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::layoutChanged(QList<QPersistentModelIndex>,QAbstractItemModel::LayoutChangeHint)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::modelReset()
```

I've tried on Windows with Qt 6.2 and Linux with Qt 6.4.1.

**Edit:** using `current` instead of `selected` in qml worked for single cell selection and selected cell color, but the error still persists, and it works only for a single cell selection not row selection.

Comment: Typo: change to `super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)` or just remove the arguments, since they are implicit since Python 3: `super().__init__(parent)`.